# return 2 values to controller, text remains NULL

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

trying to pass 2 values back to the controller id', and 'text'...id passes ok but text always returns nulll any idea why?

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <input type="hidden" id="AlertFreeTextId" name="AlertFreeTextId" value="@Model.AlertFreeTextId" />
   <input type="hidden" id="Text" name="Text" value="@Model.Text" />
   <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Text)
      @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Text, new { @class = "form-control" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Text)
   </div>
<div>
   <a href='@Url.Action("CreateAlertFreeText", "AlertFreeText", new { id = Model.AlertFreeTextId, text = Model.Text})'>
   <button class="btn btn-primary">@T("Save")</button>
   </a>  
</div>  
</div>
```

//controller

```
public ActionResult CreateAlertFreeText(int id, string text)
{
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a button inside a link?

Answer (score 0):

This line here:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("CreateAlertFreeText", "AlertFreeText", new { id = Model.AlertFreeTextId, text = Model.Text})'>
```

All this is doing is getting the text that was passed into the View.  I assume when you call the view, Model.Text is null, so that's exactly what it's returning.

You need to pull the data from the form when you submit like that.

I'd suggest creating either using a form post, or calling a jquery method to do the post where you can pull the form data.

Maybe something like this:  (warning: untested!)

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" id="AlertFreeTextId" name="AlertFreeTextId" value="@Model.AlertFreeTextId" />
    <input type="hidden" id="Text" name="Text" value="@Model.Text" />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Text)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Text, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Text)
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href='#' id='alertFreeTextLink'>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">@T("Save")</button>
        </a>  
    </div>  
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#alertFreeTextLink").click(function() {
           var url = '@Url.Action("CreateAlertFreeText", "AlertFreeText", 
               new { id = Model.AlertFreeTextId })';
           url = url + "&text=" + $("#Text").val();

           $.ajax({
               url: url
           })
           .done(function(response) {
               /// Do something here
           });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Also, why do you have this line: "<input type="hidden" id="Text" name="Text" value="@Model.Text" />"?  You now have 2 fields with the ID of "Text".  Remove this.

Comment: im afraid this didnt work....@Url.Action("CreateAlertFreeText", "AlertFreeText", flaggs up as unterminated string constant if that helps at all?

Comment: i tried adding an aleri it doesnt reach inside the script and yes i have refenced jquery